# Does using ES6 modules improve intellisense on VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

One of my big complaints about working with JavaScript, at least the way I've done it until now (mainly because of libraries I've used which aren't ES6 modules), is that since you include all files in the HTML file, you don't really have a reference to other files you're using in the script, so when I work with VS Code's ESLint plugin, it highlights syntax errors just fine but I wish it could go the extra mile showing Intellisense suggestions for the other JS files.

I was wondering, does using ES6 modules produce the result I want? And is there a way to have such behavior even when working with the "include everything in the HTML" approach?

Comment: There's many, many, many different ways to improve JavaScript intellisence. User a better IDE, add Reference Paths, ES6 Modules and/or classes, TypeScript, etc...

Comment: What is a better IDE than Code for frontend stuff? I honestly couldn't find anything better until now

Comment: I'd recommend JetBrains WebStorm. Hands down the best JavaScript / Front End IDE. VSCode is nothing but a modern day version of Notepad++

Comment: @mwilson - That bit about VSCode is completely and utterly incorrect. You must not have looked at VSCode in ***years***. (It **does** lag behind WebStorm, though, being dramatically younger..)

Comment: What are some relevant features WebStorm has that VS Code doesn't?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I disagree. I still use VSCode on a daily basis but it's mainly to leverage the extensions (notably azure extensions) rather than actually coding in it. I find the actual code editing experience to be quite poor. This is why I (in my personal opinion) consider VSCode a modern day version of Notepadd++. Notepad++ was just a text editor with some helpful plugins. VSCode is the same (but it's got much. much, much better extensions and lots of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using JavaScript module syntax means VSCode can find the things you're referring to in other files and provide IntelliSense for them.

For instance, if you have `foo.js`:

```
export class Foo {
    doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and you have `bar.js`:

```
import {Foo} from "./bar.js";
```

at that point, typing `const f = new` will make it offer you `Foo` (amongst other things). Once you've completed that line:

```
const f = new Foo();
```

at that point, typing `f.` will show you `f.doSomething()` as an autocomplete suggestion.